# How to set gin mode to release mode?

Tags: go, go-gin

I need to set gin mode to release mode. How should I do it?

Now when I run my API there is a hint like this:

```
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
```

I tried `gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)` but it does not work. I initialize my router here:

```
gin.SetMode(gin.releaseMode)    
router := gin.Default()
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to call `SetMode` method before you initialize the gin router. E.x:

```
gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
router := gin.New()
```

Answer (score 27):

Just set `GIN_MODE=release` to your environment config.

Comment: Env config? you meant the `.env` file

Comment: Not sure if that'll work. You can simply set env name in our console before starting the application or can pass in as single statement like `GIN_MODE=release go run main.go`

Comment: @iambatman you would have to use a library to load an env file.

Answer (score 5):

```
gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
```

This works. Remember that you need to set this before creating the router in your init function/main. It does not seem to work otherwise
i.e Your code would look something like this.

```
func init() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    r := NewRouter()
    err := r.Run("8080")
}
```

The init function is called for each source file after all the packages are imported and the variables are initialized.
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init

Answer (score 4):

Just add `gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)` in your main function.

Answer (score -2):

It would seem you do this by calling the [`SetMode`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#SetMode) method from within your app. Probably in your `main`, or possibly in an `init` function.

Comment: Yes I do, I call it in main function. So where is the right place to call it?